# I don't understand how my list index is out of range

Tags: python, list, indexoutofboundsexception

j stops counting when it hits 5 although my range ends at 11.

Why is it happening and how can I solve it?

Part of my code that holds the problem:

```
dice1 = random.randrange(1,7)

def probabilities_sum():
    print('\nprobability for 2 dices:')
    for j in range(1, 12):
        percentage_2 = (count[j] / freq) * 100
        procent_2 = str(percentage_2)
        print('this is J', j)
        print(j + 1, ':', procent_2)
```

Comment: What is `count`?

Comment: count counts the sum of 2 dices (from 2 to 12)

Comment: give code of count what you have written.Without that it is difficult to solve your problem

Comment: The count() method returns the number of elements with the specified value which can b any type (string, number, list, tuple, etc.). The value to searched for.

Comment: Can you show the code of count() ? i think its the source of problem @Khan

Comment: for one, you keep saying `count()` method on the comments, but in your code you use it as a mapping, with the `[]` operator, not as a method.

Comment: I did not set a count list, but have now after people have pointed it out. I didn't really understand count() since this is my first time using it. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are mistaken is your are starting your loop from `1`, and your `count` `index` is starting from `0`, so when you are calculating `percentage_2` so it was starting from `index 1` e.g: `percentage_2 = (count[1] / freq)*100`, it was skipping your `0th index` and when you reached on `j=11` so there is an `index range` of `count` is `0-10` and there is no value lies on `count[11]` that's why there was an `index out of range error`.

```
import random
count = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dice1 = random.randrange(1,7)
freq = 12
def probabilities_sum():
    print('\nprobability for 2 dices:')
    for j in range(1, 12):
        percentage_2 = (count[j - 1] / freq) * 100
        procent_2 = str(percentage_2)
        print('this is J', j)
        print(j + 1, ':', procent_2)

probabilities_sum()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome. Kindly mark this answer as your solution. Thank you.. :)